# Flutter Firestore permission denied

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Receiving this error when trying to read from my firebase firestore collection. It's a public read only collection

> E/flutter ( 2038): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

Here's my security rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /trainers {
      allow read : if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I've also tried setting the rules like this

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /trainers {
      allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

My query

```
firebaseDb.collection("trainers").get().then((value) => {
  print(value)
});
```

main func

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  setSystemOverlay(getIsDarkMode());

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of your `main.dart`?

Comment: updated question with main

Answer (score 1):

Not works, I'm use Flutter StreamBuilder and my rules in Firestore

But, before works, I don't touch enythink only live to works, sorry my english is bad.

Comment: StreamBuilder is not relate to Firestore rules

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your security rules to the following:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, so there must be something wrong with my rules definition

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution, the rules syntax needs to be like so

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /trainers/{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `=**` is not needed for your current read, and merely ensures that you also grant access to all documents in subcollections. If that is not what you want, consider using this `match /trainers/{document}`